# Issue with UIImage files not being found on phone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, xamarin.ios

Note: Using Monotouch. I have a directory called Images where I have all my PNG files. In my code I have the following

_imgMinusDark = UIImage.FromFile("images/MinusDark.png");

On the simulator it runs fine, on the phone it's null. I have the Images folder content (all the PNGs) in my MonoDevelop marked as Content in terms of Build Action.

What am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Bundle's path to the full path using Path.Combine(bundlepath, "images/MinusDark.png")

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the case for Mono, but with standard UIKit the `imageNamed` method is case sensitive on the device and case insensitive on the simulator, which can lead to the exact problem you're describing.

Comment: I double checked that my case is the same. Thanks though.

Comment: Is this happening for all of your images, or just the one? Could it be that Mono expects a backslash instead of a forward slash? Only other thing I can think of...

Comment: This is happening for all my images when deployed to the phone. The slash thing is / and is used for both the phone and simulator. Simulator it's fine, iPhone it isn't.